# SQL Commands Concept

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country>1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
```

I want to know when that compares the value of Country and 1000...,

1:what is the result after comparison?

2:what is the value of Country in this comparasion(askicode or....)?
(Country is string like usa uk and some thing like that)

Comment: what datatype is country and what does the data look like - ie all alpha, alphanumeeric , numeric, contains nulls? also please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

Do this select:

```
SELECT *, Country>1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as Comparision
FROM Customers
ORDER BY Country>1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
```

This will add a new column, with the name (=alias) `Comparison`. This will show the value of that expression.